# Excel change value shown without changing real value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

Basically I want to set up a cell which behaves similar to this:

When I enter values from 1-12, the cell shows "January" - "December", but the cell value retains the original value (1 - 12)

Above is just an example. The shown value I want is in a lookup table.

Can this be done **without macro?** I'm asking this because the users do not how to enable macro (yes they are) or freaked when seeing the yellow bar offering to enable macro.

Edit:
I think I've seen similar function of this in Access, called "lookup field".

Comment: In excel the function Vlookup can do the same.

Comment: Forgive me for not being clear enough. I want this to be done in the same cell as the input, i.e:
when I type "NY" in A1, then **A1** will show "New York" instead "NY", but when I edit A1, the value will remain "NY".

Comment: I think this is not possible as the cell may contain one value and no alias

Comment: What about adding a form field for selecting a month? It changes value in cell (which can be hidden - or under form object) and in the table is displayed an alias only. See: http://pasteboard.co/wEBRbWsQw.gif It's completely without macros.

Comment: This is simple to implement with a macro...re-consider your decision to avoid macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively unknown feature is to display additional text in the cell using custom formats.

Basically there typically four formats that you can apply and each format is separated by a `;`  The four formats are for positive numbers, negative numbers, zero and text.

You can create conditional values outside those four formats though with something like this `[=1]"January"; [=2]"February"`

The cell will evaluate to the number but display the text.  It's not a complete answer as I could only make it work with conditional value numbers but could be useful in other situations.

For more information see: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-custom-number-formats.htm

Comment: This is the closest to what I want! Too bad we can't reference cell or text for the conditional, but this open up a new possibility! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very easy.

Pick some cell, say **D1** and enter the value **2**.  Then apply the custom format:

```
"February";;;
```

[image]

The cell *displays* February, but the value is **2**.

Just change the format to match the month.

If you are willing to accept macros, you could have the macro automatically format the cell after the user has entered the value.

Comment: Would you need to apply this to every cell? What if the value changes? Say OP changed from 2 to 7, the cell would still read February.

Comment: @jrichall  The OP stated "a cell".  So I assume a **single** cell.  But it could be applied to a group of cells....as you point out the disadvantage is that the user must update the format every time the cell value is changed...that is why I suggested using a VBA macro.

Comment: I will say VBA was intimidating when I was getting started with it, but "problems" like this are what lead me to becoming more and more comfortable with them.

Comment: @jrichall  You and I are in complete agreement!  But the OP may have users who are macrophobic..

Comment: Building off this idea, you could create a bunch of conditional format rules. Under Cond. Formatting select more rules then "Use a formula". Enter "=$A1=1" then change the number format like Gary's Student has above. You'll need to do this 12 times though, as "IF" formulas get a little tricky with Cond. Formatting. "=$A1=2", "=$A1=3", etc

Comment: @jrichall  I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dead set against macros, you can use a helper column and an Index/Match formula.

Here's what I did:
[image: Lookup Table]
The table on the left is where you enter your tracking. Add a helper column to either enter your numbers (1-12), or one to show the month. Then, assign your values in your "lookup table".

In this example, I entered the formula into the 1-12 tracking column. The formula goes like this:
=INDEX([Result you want to show], MATCH([Criteria],[Where to Match],0[zero means exact match]))
So in this example I used

```
=INDEX(Lookup[Lookup Field],MATCH([Helper],Lookup[Tracking Value],0))
```

I named my lookup table "Lookup", so I can use structured references. Instead of using "H6:H18". You can certainly use cell ranges/references. I just prefer table/[structured references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e).

Then, just hide your column with the numbers and only your Months will show.